# Rails реализация ЧПУ

Tags: чпу, ruby-on-rails

Как правильно реализовать возможность выбирать вид ссылки, то есть чтобы была воможность менять формат ссылки, например, как в `wordpress`: `url/post/id urp/post/title url/date/title url/title`

Правильным ли решением будет сделать таблицу settings со строкой url_pattern, содержащей, к примеру, номер варианта или нужный формат. И сделать в application хелпер, который будет получать значение параметра `url_pattern` из базы (или из глобальной переменной) и через case подставлять нужный формат ссылки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если вы хотите, чтобы запись отвечала по любому из этих урлов одновременно, то я сделал бы примерно так (код не тестирован и намеренно упрощён):

В routes:

```
get 'post/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :by_id_or_title
get 'date/:date' => 'posts#show', as: :by_date
```

posts_controller:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_title_or_id(params[:id])||Post.find_by_date(params[:date])
end
```

models/post:

```
def self.find_by_title_or_id(id)
  return nil if id.blank?
  find_by(title: id)||find_by(id: id)
end

def self.find_by_date(date)
  return nil if date.blank?
  find_by(date_field: date)
end
```

Ссылки создавать примерно так: `link_to 'Link by date', by_date_path(@post.date_field)`

Посмотреть маршруты: rake routes. Почитать подробнее: http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing

При работе с датами уделите внимание формату, дабы то, что вы предаёте хелперу совпадало с тем, что вы ищете по базе.

Comment: Но это как обрабатывать пути, а как бы вы сделали возможность менять формат ссылок для to_link. хелпер который получает параметр и через case выводит нужный вид url будет нормально или можно придумать лучше?

Comment: директива "as: :by_date" в роутах создаст хелпер. Работает примерно так: link_to 'Link by date', by_date_path(@post.date_field)

Comment: Обновил ответ...